# reprex ignores output of system()

Tags: r, reprex

Consider the following cross-platform test:

```
> system('echo hello')
hello
```

If in RStudio I copy the string `system('echo hello')` and the run `reprex::reprex()` the output is not captured:

[image]

Is there any way to capture the output?  I'm on macOS.

Comment: `system('echo hello', intern=TRUE)`?

Comment: Yeah already tried that - no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps setting `std_out_err = TRUE` does the job. From the function documentation:

> **std_out_err** Logical. Whether to append a section for output sent to stdout and stderr by the reprex rendering process. This can be
>   necessary to reveal output if the reprex spawns child processes or
>   system() calls. Note this cannot be properly interleaved with output
>   from the main R process, nor is there any guarantee that the lines
>   from standard output and standard error are in correct chronological
>   order. See callr::r() for more. Read more about opt().

```r
system("echo hello")
x <- 1
x
#> [1] 1
```

standard output and standard error

```sh
hello
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>